# Asp .net core 1.1 web app publish to azure can't find resource

Tags: asp.net, linux, azure, configuration, asp.net-core

I just tried to publish my asp .net core web application to Azure and cant get it to work. When I hit browse I get this message

[Picture when I try to browse to my published website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBDf6.png)

I've tried to see in the log to figure out what the problem is and found this message

```
<Error>
  <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>
        The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:64038d84-0001-0068-1019-55d321000000 Time:2016-12-13T08:19:53.3494003Z
    </Message>
</Error>
```

I thought it might be the in the 'startup.cs' in the project where I try to find the connection string.

Github link to project: https://github.com/AlexJCarstensen/ITTWEB-ASPNetCore

I try to get the connection string link this:

```
services.AddDbContext<EmbeddedStockContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Ive added this setting to *Application settings* for the app in both *App Settings* and *Connection strings* but still it cant find it.

So the question is how do I get the connectionstring from Azure in its *Application settings*?

Info: I'm developing on linux, so dont have access to visual studio.

Hope you can help

Regards Alex

Comment: Azure use IIS "before" your site. You have `web.config` with instructions for IIS. Enable logging there (`stdoutLogEnabled="true"`) - this will dump all stdout of Kestrel to file (path is in web.config too). Then check this logs for exact errors. You may use azure-preinstalled [kudo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service) for both tasks.

Comment: Thanks ! Found out that azure maybe doesn't support "builder.AddUserSecrets" or atleast that was the error message. So know it works.. Now I just have to figure out how to run the migrations on the database.

Answer (score 0):

After following up on Dmitry comment I found the logs where the detailed error message was.

The error message was this:

```
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could     not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'ITTWEB-ASPNetCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationExtensions.AddUserSecrets(IConfigurationBuilder configuration)
at ITTWEB_ASPNetCore.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in D:\home\site\repository\ITTWEB-ASPNetCore\Startup.cs:line 38
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, String environmentName)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactoryService(FactoryService factoryService, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://localhost:28800
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

So apparently Azure does not support the ability of UserSecrets.
If you want to know more about UserSecrets.
Microsoft has some information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets#security-app-secrets

In our project we used it to develop on a windows and a linux machine to keep the different connectionstring in a userSecret. And this was not applicable with Azure.

Hope this helps others.

Alex.

Comment: Azure supports UserSecrets, but there is a difference between running locally or in Azure. Locally site works because you have `project.json` with `userSecretId`. In Azure, publishing does not include it to output ([issue 62](https://github.com/aspnet/UserSecrets/issues/62#issuecomment-232896355)). And bug was fixed with breaking changes (see [announce 209](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/209))